# Connect to Kafka with TrustStore / KeyStore certificates using .NET

Tags: .net, ssl, apache-kafka

I'm trying to connect to KAFKA with SaslSsl using .NET 6. I'm not hosting the server and this are the provided connection details:

```
ssl.truststore.location=truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=xx
ssl.keystore.location=keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=xx
ssl.key.password=xx
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required \
username="user" \
password="xx;
```

Unfortunately JKS files are not supported in .NET and I received converted PEM files instead. (truststore.pem and keystore.pem)
Truststores are also not supported in .NET, so we need to use the PEM files as Certificate.

Do you know what exact settings I have to use for my situation so I can defined the certificated with corresponding passwords.

```
ConsumerConfig config = new ConsumerConfig
{
    Debug = "broker,topic,msg,security",
    BootstrapServers = "xx",
    GroupId = "xx",
    AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest,
    EnableAutoCommit = false,
    SslCaLocation = "truststore.pem",
    SslCertificateLocation = "keystore.pem",
    SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocol.SaslSsl,
    SaslMechanism = SaslMechanism.Plain,
    SaslUsername = "user",
    SaslPassword = "xx"
};
```

The error I got:

```
Certificate verify failed: broker certificate could not be verified, verify that ssl.ca.location is correctly configured or root CA certificates are installed
```

Comment: DO you have any update on this topic?

Answer (score -1):

Why do you use both certificate and username/password? Check what
is the authentication mechanism where your broker.

For my case, I am using basic authentication in my broker. So I just need to use username and password.

```
var config = new ConsumerConfig
        {
            BootstrapServers = "my broker urls",
            GroupId = groupName,
            AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Latest,
            SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocol.SaslSsl,
            SaslMechanism = SaslMechanism.ScramSha512,
            SaslUsername = "myusername",
            SaslPassword = "mypassword",
            EnableAutoCommit = false
        };
```

Comment: Sounds like you're using SASL_PLAINTEXT not SASL_SSL

Comment: Both username/password and the certificate are probably required because of a security requirement. The example above can't be used, because it required me to set a certificate.